# Freebase select all cities from administrative division

Tags: jquery, freebase

Any ideas on how to select all citytowns from certain administrative division? Can be any country. Tried to search by fips_10_4_region_code but can't get it working, it seems that /location/citytown doesn't have this property

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, but then, this may be something freebase specific....

Answer (score 1):

If you know the Freebase ID of the administrative division then you can find all city/towns contained by it using [a query like this](http://tinyurl.com/23l4q4a):

```
[{
  "id":   null,
  "name": null,
  "type": "/location/citytown",
  "/location/location/containedby": {
    "id": "/en/california"
  }
}]​
```

There's also an experimental [Geosearch API](http://api.freebase.com/api/service/geosearch?help) which can find geolocated cities within given topic's shape (if it has one).